# Default padding RecyclerView on pre lollipop

Tags: android, padding, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` on an activity and its items are just a `RelativeLayout` without any `CardView`, the `RecyclerView` has some right padding on devices running api lower than 21.
Items and `RecyclerView` itself doesn't have any margin or padding and everything works fine only on api grater than 21
How can i remove this padding shown by red arrows?

[image]

EDIT:
Activity xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="ir.peykebartar.android.activity.SearchActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_search_activity" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/resultList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#567"
            android:layout_above="@id/listFooterContainer"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <ir.peykebartar.android.view.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_large"
            android:text="@string/load_error"
            android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
            android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- FAB -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/floatActionButton_marginBottom"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:backgroundTint="#9A12B3"
        app:fabSize="normal" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

RecyclerView item xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/swipeLayoutParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ir.peykebartar.android.view.CustomSwipeLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!-- Bottom View Start-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@null"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        .
        .
        .

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Bottom View End-->

    <!-- Surface View Start -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        .
        .
        .

    </LinearLayout>

</ir.peykebartar.android.view.CustomSwipeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show some code

Comment: Plzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz...put some code.....

Comment: what code u need? adapter? xml?

Comment: XML obviously in this case..both item.xml and recycler view..

Comment: @AnoopM here is my codes

Comment: may be cardUseCompatPadding() will help https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_android.support.v7.cardview:cardUseCompatPadding

Comment: As i said before I don't use `CardView` as recyclerview items